# How to recover files from uninstalled odoo instances

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I was working on Ubuntu cloud server and unfortunately i had to uninstall the odoo instance after some problems. Now I am facing the problem with attachments in the newly restored database. Unfortunately the filestore folder of previous odoo version has got deleted and I do not have the source of file store for some attachments.

please guide me immediately

Answer (score 1):

Usually file by default Odoo filestore is on database only so if you dropped the database then you have already loose the filestore with database, but if you using external file store then you still can get your file store from user home  folder, usually in Ubuntu filestore is by default under file path  **/home/username/.local/share/Odoo/filestore** here you will find folder with your database name. You can copy and use same filestore on new database by renaming the folder name.

Bests

Comment: Hello, Checking my server I realize that I have filestore databases that no longer exist. Can I remove these directories without causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

odoo database and filestore are generally a working pair as the database references filestore locations.  If you have restored a database from another server, then I suggest you also copy the data folder from that server.

Odoo has a builtin backup and restore tool but I find that it sometimes fails for very large backups.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-automatic-odoo-backup/